# Find the eigenvector and eigenvalues for the following 3 x 3 Matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations

$$ \pmatrix{5 & 8 & 16 \\ 
4 & 1 & 8 \\ 
-4 &-4 & -11} $$

I already got the eigenvalues that is $\lambda = 1$ and $-3$. And I managed to solve the eigenvector corresponding to the value $\lambda = 1$ which is $(k,k/2,-k/2)$. But for $\lambda = -3$, I struggle to solve the system of equations . Please help.

Comment: As an aside, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) has information on how to type with MathJax and $\LaTeX$ so you have nice looking matrices like $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}5&8&16\\4&1&8\\-4&-4&-11\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, making your question more readable.

Comment: Changed.Mind to answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\lambda=-3$ we consider $A-\lambda I = A-(-3)I=A+3I$

$\begin{bmatrix}5&8&16\\
4&1&8\\
-4&-4&-11\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}3&0&0\\0&3&0\\0&0&3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 8&8&16\\4&4&8\\-4&-4&-8\end{bmatrix}$

We try to ask: what is the eigenspace for the eigenvalue $-3$?

I.e. we try to ask: what is the nullspace of $A+3I$?

I.e. we ask for the solution set to $(A+3I)v=0$

Using standard techniques, we can consider the augmented matrix:

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 8&8&16&0\\4&4&8&0\\-4&-4&-8&0\end{array}\right]$ and row reduce.

Noticing that every row is a multiple of one another, this row reduces to:

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&2&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{array}\right]$

Interpreting this as a system of equations, this implies that:

$\begin{cases} v_1+v_2+2v_3=0\\v_2~\text{can be anything}\\ v_3~\text{can be anything}\end{cases}$

Letting $v_2=s$ and $v_3=t$, this changes the system to the form:

$\begin{cases} v_1+s+2t=0\\v_2=s\\v_3=t\end{cases} \xrightarrow{\text{which becomes}}\begin{cases}v_1=-s-2t\\v_2=s\\v_3=t\end{cases}$

this implies that the vector is of the form $\begin{bmatrix} -s-2t\\s\\t\end{bmatrix} = s\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}-2\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

These two vectors then form a basis for the eigenspace for the eigenvalue $-3$.

(*of course, there are infinitely many correct answers for the problem, so long as the two vectors you choose span the same space as the two vectors I give above*)

Comment: How do we know that v2 and  v3 can be anything and not  v1?

Comment: @SyedAriff it is common practice to have it be the values corresponding to the locations of the pivots be the variables described by the free variables, and the values corresponding to the columns without pivots to be the free variables, however as mentioned there are infinitely many correct answers to the problem.  You could if you wanted to let $v_1$ and $v_3$ be the values which could be anything, thereby making $v_2$ depend on the values of $v_1$ and $v_3$.  Doing so would give the two vectors $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\-2\\1\end{bmatrix}$ which is also correct

Comment: The point being, among the values $v_1,v_2,v_3$, once you pick two of them to be free, the third can not be "anything" anymore and will depend on the values picked for the others.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, the matrix for the eigenvalue -3 should have rows 8,8,16; 4,4,8; and -4,-4,-8. The second and third rows are multiples of the first. Appropriate row operations eliminate them. You end with the equation x+y+2z=0, which has solutions equal to the span of the vectors (-1,1,0) and (-2,0,1). I hope this helps.

Comment: Third row is $(-4,-4,-8)$, seems to be a typo.

Comment: @Abstraction - You are so right. I will edit to change.